# remove specific classes within a div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to remove all specific classes within a specific div. I've tried various jQuery code and cannot get it working. I want to remove "remove all of this" below

```
<div id="commRollover">

<div class='nRegions' style='display:none;' id='Belgium' ><b><em>Belgium</em></b><BR><BR>                                                    

<div class='commIntro'>remove all of this</div>
<BR /></div>
<BR /></div>
```

I tried the following:

```
$("#commRollover").removeClass("commIntro");
```

Comment: You want to remove the div itself, or the class from the div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure whether you want to remove the class from the `<div>` or the `<div>` with the specified class. Both solutions are outlined below:

**Remove the class from the div:**

```
$('#commRollover .commIntro').removeClass('commIntro');
```

Documentation: [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

**Remove the div with a specific class:**

```
$('#commRollover .commIntro').remove();
```

Documentation: [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Awesome thanks! I didn't realize I wasn't asking question correctly. I wanted to remove all divs with a specific class, so the second option worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Do this -

```
$("#commRollover").find('.commIntro').remove(); // removes the entire div
```

Answer (score 0):

The "removeClass" function will remove the class "commIntro" from the DIV, effectively resulting in HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class=''>remove all of this</div>
```

If what you actually want to do is remove the text "remove all of this" from the page, as you stated in your question, then try this:

```
$('.commIntro').html('');
```

Which will effectively result in HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class='commIntro'></div>
```